# How to create a node and pass it to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, textnode

I have the following:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>Here is some text blah <span class="tag">meme</span> hello world.</p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is set the cursor after the span.  I can use the following but this doesn't let me tell the cursor to go after the span:

```
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var textNode = document.getElementById("comment_content_new").firstChild;
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(textNode, 7);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
```

Any ideas how I can tell var textNode to go after the span?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create a TextNode or place the caret at a given position? Your question title and body don't match...

Comment: what is textNode? what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be with jquery

```
$("span").after(textNode);
```